# Preimage of open set is Lebesgue measurable only if the function itself is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

It is a simple result in my book saying the proof is trivial, but I can not seem to show it. If someone can provide a hint just to help me begin my proof, it would be of assistance.

Assume you know that $g:D\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable. Then how to go about showing that $g^{-1}(U)$ is also measurable, where $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ is open?

Comment: What is $D$? A subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $D\subset \mathbb{R}$ yes, which is also Lebesgue measurable

Comment: How does your book define a measurable function?

Comment: A function $f$ is said to be measurable if $\{f<\alpha\}$ is measurable for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, (i.e, the preimages)

Comment: Any open subset of $\mathbb R$ can be decomposed as as countable disjoint union of open intervals, which in turn can be obtained via countable unions, intersections, and complements of intervals of the form $(-\infty, \alpha)$. And $f^{-1}$ plays nicely with all of these operations.

Answer (score 1):

According to your definition of measurability, we know that $g^{-1}((-\infty,a))$ is measurable for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$. This implies that
$$ g^{-1}([a,b))=g^{-1}((-\infty,b))\setminus g^{-1}((-\infty,a))$$
is measurable for all real numbers $a<b$, and by taking unions of such intervals we see that sets of the form $g^{-1}((a,b))$ and $g^{-1}((a,\infty))$ are measurable for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. In other words $g^{-1}(I)$ is measurable for all open intervals $I$.

Finally, since every open subset $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a countable union of disjoint open intervals $I_j$, it follows that $g^{-1}(U)=\cup_jg^{-1}(I_j)$ is measurable.

Comment: For what it's worth: how to decompose every open set in $\Bbb R$ into a disjoint Union of countable open intervals is, first realise $\Bbb R$ has a countable basis consisting of open intervals, then every open set is a countable Union of open intervals, and finally take connected components.

Answer (score 0):

For the completeness of @carmichael561 answer:
If $\mathcal{G}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Borel-measurable, then for any set $U \in \mathcal{B}$ (where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$) i.e.: $\mathcal{G}^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal{B}$ (this is by definition of measurable function).

A $\sigma$-algebra is closed under unions and intersections, so if $I1, I2 \in \mathcal{B}$ then: $I1 \cup I2$ and $I1 \cap I2$ are in $\mathcal{B}$. This is for all set in the $\sigma$-algebra.